# HTML section doesn't match container height

Tags: html, css, containers

I made an HTML section. The child is a container with defined height and a few other CSS properties. But as far as I know, nothing that would change the parent. So normally the section would match the height of this container but in this case, it doesn't. Why?

[image]

```css
#referencesContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: var(--colorFont);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML section&container-->
<section id="references">
  <div id="referencesContainer" class="lockContainer">
    <h2 class="paddingBottom30"></h2>
    <span>
       <br>
       <br>
    </span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you post the css for the section?

Comment: I created a snipped for you, please edit is so that we can see the actual problem.

Comment: According to your snippet, the `section` element doesn't have a given height, so it takes the height of its content, which is `300px` of the container, plus `60px` padding top and bottom...

Comment: The snippet is not having all details of the parent container. If you could create the complete thing, it will be easy to collaborate. You may update this: https://jsfiddle.net/geekays/mL1y9cak/1/

Comment: Not the answer, but beware you are defining the padding twice, via `padding` shorthand and `padding-top`

Comment: section height is matching with container height, why did you say that, it is not matching?. is that section height also should include margin of container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your parent section

```
<section id="references">
```

define an class to this section like this

```
<section id="references" class="parentclass">
```

Then gives create css like this

```css
.parentclass{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: var(--colorFont);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
  }
```

This is your child class

```
 <div id="referencesContainer" class="lockContainer">
```

Define their css as like below

```css
.lockContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: var(--colorFont);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Your problem is causing by parent class you have to make use they didn't overite it. eg: if 4/4 square are parent class and a child class are 2/2. now i want to make child class 6/6. is it possible.
you never make different without defining css of parent class.

you have to write css of parent class if you want to use id do like this

```css
#references{
...
...
....
....
...
}
```